# How to run only one "if" statement (can't use "else")?

Tags: c, if-statement

So I'm doing this assignment and I have to use 5 if statements for grading ... my problem is that after I enter a score 
my first attempt

```
if(grade >= 90 )
{
    puts("A");
}

if(grade >= 80 )
{
    puts("B");
}

if(grade >=70 )
{
    puts("C");
}

if(grade >=60 )
{
    puts("D");
}
if(grade >=50 )
{
    puts("F");
}
```

when I run this program I get all the grade letters.. for example if I type 96 I should only get A... however I get A B C D F different attempt

```
if(grade >= 100 || grade>= 90 )
{
    puts("A");
}

if(grade >= 89 || grade>= 80 )
{
    puts("B");
}

if(grade >=79 || grade>= 70)
{
    puts("C");
}

if(grade >=69 || grade>= 60)
{
    puts("D");
}
if(grade >=59 || grade>= 50)
{
    puts("F");
}
```

Comment: I cant use Else.... only IF statements

Comment: @user2246674: *"I cant use Else.... only IF statements"* Nonsense. All due respect, you must be misinterpreting that restriction.

Comment: we have not learned break and goto yet... but we use return for functions...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think this is a reasonable question for a student trying to understand a legitimate error in his/her code. I would consider it reasonable (for learning purposes) even if the constraint was self-imposed. Just my 2c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `else`:

```
if(grade >= 90 )
{
    puts("A");
}
else if(grade >= 80 )
{
    puts("B");
}
// and so on
```

Without it, well, of course a `grade` of (say) 92 is `>= 90` and *also* `>= 80`.

---

You've said below that for reasons beyond understanding, you're not allowed to use `else`. I'm sure that's not the case, because it would be someone teaching you to write bad code. You must be misunderstanding the requirement. But if it *were* true, surely the answer is obvious?

```
if(grade >= 90 )
{
    puts("A");
}

if(grade < 90 && grade >= 80 )
{
    puts("B");
}
// and so on
```

Comment: I can only use if statements... because the second part of the question is using nested else if...

Comment: @user2168344: Nonsense. That restriction makes absolutely **zero** sense. All due respect, I think you're misinterpreting it.

Comment: So I have to use else... because the question only says use 5 if statements

Comment: @user2168344: Again: I think you're misinterpreting the question, because that's a nonsense restriction suggesting you write poor code. But surely the answer if that *were* true is obvious? `if (grade < 90 && grade >= 80)`...?

Comment: I hope that I misunderstood the question, because I spent a lot of time trying to figure out a way to do it using only if statements... so I should do if (grade < 90 && grade >=80)

Answer (score 3):

Reverse the order of your checks. Upgrade the letter grade as the higher checks pass.

```
const char *lettergrade = "F";
if (grade >= 60) {
    lettergrade = "D";
}
if (grade >= 70) {
    lettergrade = "C";
}
if (grade >= 80) {
    lettergrade = "B";
}
if (grade >= 90) {
    lettergrade = "A";
}
puts(lettergrade);
```

Answer (score 2):

While a "logical" transformation would be to use an `else`, if that is absolutely banned for some [silly] reason, one can also approach this using a function! It avoids the use of `else` *and* results in tidier and more modular code - such a construct is not uncommon in my code. (That being said, it might not be what the teacher is looking for ;-)

Create a function with the signature `char* getGrade(int score)`. Then instead of "puts" in the `if`, simply `return` (the correct value) and use the first approach posed. The `return` will "end the function right then"  and thus not execute the additional `if` statements which solves the original problem. Then the result can be easily used:

```
puts(getGrade(theirScore));
```

Good luck with these sorts of "assignments"!

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you're so uneasy about else, you could just do -

```
if(grade >= 90 )
{
    puts("A");
}

if(grade >= 80 && grade <90 )
{
    puts("B");
}

if(grade >=70 && grade < 80 )
{
    puts("C");
}

if(grade >=60 && grade < 70)
{
    puts("D");
}
if(grade >=50 && grade < 60)
{
    puts("F");
}
```

What you wrote with ORs makes no sense, if grade >= 100, then of course grade>= 90, there's no reason to add that condition (and it won't do the job for you)

Answer (score 1):

you can define 2 constraints for example:

```
if (grade >=90){
//do something
}

if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90){
//do something
} // and so on...
```

This ensures that the piece of code inside the if statement would only run if BOTH the conditions are satisfied. The && symbol represents 'AND'

Comment: Yes. Like i said the && forces a limit on the range ie min and max

Answer (score 1):

Use else ifs:

```
if(grade >= 90 )
{
    puts("A");
}

else if(grade >= 80 )
{
    puts("B");
}

else if(grade >=70 )
{
    puts("C");
}

else if(grade >=60 )
{
    puts("D");
}
else if(grade >=50 )
{
    puts("F");
}
```

However, to follow good practices and to make your program easy to extend and maintain, you might want to structure it in a more intelligent way. A good approach would be to store an array of a structure that holds the grade threshold and the corresponding letter. If you keep it sorted by grade threshold, you could then iterate through the array from right to left and stop in the first position for which the student grade is greater than the threshold. Think about it!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(grade>=90)
puts("A");

if(grade>=80&&grade<90)
puts("B");

if(grade>=70&&grade<80)
puts("c");

if(grade>=60&&grade<70)
puts("D");

if(grade>=50&&grade<60)
puts("E");
```

Try this, I think it works.